# Unable to access discord bot instance in quart lifecycle

Tags: python, discord.py, celery, quart

I'm confused with regards to event loops, this might be a common question because it seems like people are using discord.py with quart. I'm trying to integrate discord.py, quart, and celery.

I have a manage.py that looks like this. It exposes app, and celery which would be used by hypercorn and celery respectively. I'm trying to get the discord.py instance to be used by celery

```py
# ./manage.py
from backend import create_app, create_celery
from backend.config import Config

app = create_app()

# celery tasks
celery = create_celery(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = 8000)
```

In ./backend/init.py I defined create_celery() and create_app()

```py
# ./backend/__init__.py
import os
import asyncio
from quart import Quart
from backend.config import Config
from discord.ext import commands
from cogs import MainCog
from celery import Celery
import backend.celeryconfig as celeryconfig


def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Quart(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    # inject discord bot
    @app.before_serving
    async def before_serving(app):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        app.discord_bot = commands.Bot(
            command_prefix=">" )
        # add cogs here
        app.discord_bot.add_cog(MainCog(app.discord_bot))

        # connect bot
        await app.discord_bot.login(Config.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
        loop.create_task(app.discord_bot.connect())

    return app

def create_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    celery.config_from_object(celeryconfig)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            async def helper(self, *args, **kwargs):
                async with app.app_context():
                    return await self.run(*args, **kwargs)

            loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() # <-- I'm confused about this
            coroutine = helper(self, *args, **kwargs)
            loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

When I call asyncio.get_running_loop() I get no running event loop

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/backend/__init__.py", line 59, in __call__
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

How can I access app.discord_bot from celery's context?

Comment: Try defining the loop in the global namespace and reference that, or pass the loop variable around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to the error but another approach is to use `discord-ext-ipc` instead to have ipc communication between discord.py and quart. In this approach increasing the number of workers in an ASGI server would increase the number of discord bot instance resulting in repeated responses on a discord server.

https://github.com/Ext-Creators/discord-ext-ipc